# How to deploy a ASMX webservice on Godaddy shared hosting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, deployment, hosting

I've created one simple 'Hello World' web service. I want to deploy it on my Godaddy shared hosting and consume it in Visual Studio. I tried searching steps for the same but didn't help much.

I already have asp.net website running on my Plesk. I want to deploy a asmx service which will be consumed by third party. Can anyone please help me with the steps to deploy on Godaddy?

Comment: GoDaddy provide 24X7 support. Call them.

Comment: Already tried. Didn't help much

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get the deployment working.

1. create your asmx webservice site.
2. create your one click publish profile.
3. publish method: FTP.
4. server --> enter: ftp//yourwebsite.com.
5. site path: /
6. username: enter your plesk account name
7. password: enter your plesk account password.
8. destination url - leave blank.

click publish - that's all you need to do.

9. create a windows form app.
10. add web ref to site.
11. I assume you know how to do the rest in order to test the "hello world" web function.

firewalls need to be setup if you have them between your visual studio and the internet.